# Little Hölder spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, holder-spaces

In this question, we have a definition of the above spaces:

[What is little Holder space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670014/what-is-little-holder-space)

How can we prove that the closure of the “smooth” functions, i.e. the little Hölder space, is not the whole space?

How can we construct a $C^{k,\alpha}$ function that cannot be approximated by smooth functions?

Questions involving the construction of a counterexample often demand significant creativity, and I don’t happen to be able to know how to start to answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely covered by the answers in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/29869). The cliff notes (WLOG $k=0$):

1. Every $f$ in $c^\alpha$ satisfies $$\lim_{t\downarrow 0} \sup_{x\neq y:|x-y|\le t} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} = 0$$
2. But for say $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$, $\sup_{x\neq y:|x-y|\le t} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^{1/2}} \ge \frac{|\sqrt t - 0|}{\sqrt{t-0}}=1$ for all $t\ge0$. [Alternatively](https://mathoverflow.net/a/35372) you can check directly that there is no smooth function close by in $C^{1/2}$. Other $\alpha\in (0,1)$ can be [treated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202662/x-alpha-as-an-example-of-an-alpha-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-function) similarly.

For the proof of 1: Let $\epsilon>0$ and $f_n$ be smooth functions with $f_n\to f$ in $C^\alpha$. Then
$$ \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} \le \frac{|f_n(x) - f_n(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + \frac{|(f-f_n)(x) - (f-f_n)(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} \le \|\nabla f_n\|_{C^0}|x-y|^{1-\alpha} +[f-f_n]_{C^\alpha}.$$
Pick $n=n(\epsilon)\gg 1$ so that $[f-f_n]_{C^\alpha} < \epsilon/2$, and then pick $t_0=t_0(n,\epsilon)$ so that $\|\nabla f_n\|_{C^0}t_0^{1-\alpha} < \epsilon/2$. It follows that for all $0<t<t_0$,  $\sup_{x\neq y:|x-y|<t} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \epsilon$, QED.

Comment: Many thanks @Calvin Khor. I am confused about the step where you bring in $\|\nabla f_n\|_{C_0}$. I suppose your definition of $\|f\|_{C_\alpha}$ is $\sup_{x,y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$. On that basis, I would have thought that where you wrote $\|\nabla f_n\|_{C_0}$ you meant to write $\|f_n\|_{C_0}$. However, you could still write $\|\nabla f_n\|_{\infty}$ but you would require the domain of the functions to be compact to use the mean-value inequality. At any rate, the proof still works

Comment: @MartinGeller you're welcome! yes I should have stated somehow that everything is local, sorry, and yes I meant $\|\nabla f\|_{C^0}$ to be precisely the sup norm of $\nabla f$.

Comment: Do you mean that local compactness of the domains of the $f_n$’s suffices to apply the mean value inequality? No need for global compactness? When you say that you meant the $C_0$ norm of the gradient to be the sup-norm, do you mean that they are equivalent or that there is a typo in your post?

Comment: @MartinGeller well, I was always considering them to be defined on some compact set, because I think of the holder condition as a local one instead of some sort of growth condition. On compact, we have mean val inequality as $f_n$s are smooth. By $C^0$ I mean the space of continuous functions (on the compact set) whose norm $\|f\|_{C^0}$ equals the $L^\infty$ norm. Hope this helps