# Example of little $\alpha$ Hölder function that is not $\beta$ Hölder, for any $\beta>\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples, holder-spaces

> What functions are in the set $$ c^\alpha \setminus \bigcup_{\beta \in (\alpha,1)} C^\beta?$$

A single example will do, but the more the merrier.

This question was natural to me after writing [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658916/little-h%C3%B6lder-spaces/4659273#4659273); all I did was summarise info that was on MO. There, it is explained that $x^\alpha$ on $[0,1]$ belongs to the set $C^\alpha \setminus c^\alpha$.

What is $c^\alpha$? It is the 'little $\alpha$-Hölder space', either defined as the closure of $C^\infty$ in the $C^\alpha$ norm, or equivalently as the subset of $C^\alpha$ functions for which $\lim_{t\downarrow 0} \sup_{0<|x-y|<t} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} = 0.$ Naturally there are the inclusions

$$ C^\infty \subset c^\alpha \subset C^\alpha$$

The question of what functions are in  $c^\alpha \setminus C^\infty$ is trivial. If $\alpha < \beta$ then we can further write

$$ C^\infty \subset c^\beta \subset C^\beta \subset c^\alpha \subset C^\alpha$$

For fixed $0<\alpha<\beta<1$, it is also trivial to see that  $ x^{(\alpha+\beta)/2}$ is in $c^\alpha \setminus C^\beta([0,1])$. The functions $x^\alpha$ are also examples of functions in $C^\alpha \setminus \bigcup_{\beta \in (\alpha,1)} C^\beta$ (this is already implied by being in $C^\alpha \setminus c^\alpha$).

Approaching from the other direction is also not interesting: the function $(x \log x)^\alpha$ on $[0,1/2]$ is easily seen to be a function that belongs to the set $$\bigcap_{\beta \in (0, \alpha) } C^\beta \setminus C^\alpha = \bigcap_{\beta \in (0, \alpha) } c^\beta \setminus C^\alpha \subset \bigcap_{\beta \in (0, \alpha) } c^\beta \setminus c^\alpha.$$

I think therefore, this question is the simplest non-trivial question that can be asked.

Any and all thoughts welcome!

Comment: I think functions of the form $f(x) = x^a \sin(x^{-b})$ for $a,b > 0$ with $f(0) = 0$ will work, maybe even when only using $b=1.$ I don't have time to double check this now, but for what it's worth, it's also the case that $\bigcup_{\beta \in (\alpha,1)} C^\beta$ is a first (Baire) category subset of $C^{\alpha}$ under their standard norms. In fact, I think "most" functions in $C^{\alpha}$ are not $C^{\beta}$ for any $\beta > \alpha$ (or even in $\bigcup_{\beta \in (\alpha,1)} C^\beta)$ at continuum many points in every interval, or something along these lines.